# Minified AngularJS gives me unreadable errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the stack trace when I use angular.js:

```
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: editorPopupManagerProvider <- editorPopupManager <- libStateManager <- libInjectionManager
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.2/$injector/unpr?p0=editorPopupManagerProvider%20%3C-%20editorPopupManager%20%3C-%20libStateManager%20%3C-%20libInjectionManager
```

And this is the stack trace when I use angular.min.js:

```
[$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.2/$injector/unpr?p0=editorPopupManagerProvider%20%3C-%20editorPopupManager%20%3C-%20libStateManager%20%3C-%20libInjectionManager
```

This is just a simple example but sometimes the minified error doesn't help even a bit.

I expect the first stack trace in both cases: When I use angular.js and angular.min.js.
I don't have a problem in the code that led to this exception. I made it on purpose to demonstrate the problem I have with angular.min.js minifying the stack trace and making it really hard to understand. If the reason it does that is to avoid end users to see the stack trace, I understand. But I need the normal-readable stack trace in order to send it to a logging server.

Comment: What is your question? What do you expect? Use the unminified version in development to make it easier to debug.

Comment: Even I face the problem, use this Dependency Annotation style `someModule.factory('greeter', ['$window', function(renamed$window) { ... }]);` in entire application. Problem is in where you have defined `editorPopupManagerProvider`. Additionally can you post `editorPopupManagerProvider` code?

Answer (score 3):

Your unknown provider name is probably being manipulated/mangled by the minifier, thus you need to use the following syntax to correct it:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl' ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    // do stuff with '$scope'
}]);
```

Note how the function is wrapped in an Array, this keeps the naming conventions of your dependencies so they can safely be remapped as Strings are not mangled:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl' ['$scope', function (a) {
    // do stuff with 'a'
}]);
```

Which you can then add your other dependencies (they need to appear in the order as they're specified):

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl' ['$scope', 'MyService', function ($scope, MyService) {
    // do stuff...
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you. I solved my problem removing uglifyjs pipe from gulp. :)

Answer (score 3):

In case, that you do use **the array declaration** for your controllers, this would most likely be of some of your **Directive** declarations. Usually we do this:

```
.controller('MyGreatCtrl',
[       '$scope','$stateParams', // even minified version does is correctly injected
function($scope , $stateParams ,) {
    ...
```

And the above code will work correctly, even if minified.

But, what we should do the same way - is the `Directive` declaration. We can do it like this *(wrong, problems when minified)*:

```
.directive('myGreatDirective',
    [function () {
        var directive =
        {
            restrict: 'E',
            ...
            controller: function ($scope , $element , $attrs) {
                ...
                };
            }],
        };
        return directive;
```

While this would be the correct way:

```
.directive('myGreatDirective',
    [function () {
        var directive =
        {
            restrict: 'E',
            ...
            // the Array declaration also here
            controller: ['$scope','$element','$attrs',
                function ($scope , $element , $attrs) {
                    ...    
                };
            }],
        };
        return directive;
```

And the link to more details [Dependency Injection](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/)

*Honestly, that was my issue ...*

Comment: you rocks. It solved my Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eProvider <- e problem thanks