# How to debug angular [$injector:modulerr] errors

Tags: angularjs, debugging, runtime-error

I have a growing angular application. From time to time, I mess things up and get an error of the type:

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module App due to:
```

It is often very difficult to find the error based on the error message, especially if there are many files with various controllers etc.

Is there a way to debug these errors in either Chrome or Firefox ?

Answer (score 32):

Just to illustrate.

This is what you get when you load **minified** version of Angular (`angular.min.js`):

```
Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error
Failed to instantiate module eduApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=e...)
    at Error (native)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:38:184
    at m (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:7:322)
    at h (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:37:275)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:37:444
    at m (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:7:322)
    at h (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:37:275)
    at fb (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:41:35)
    at d (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:19:463
```

And this is what you get when you use **unminified** version (`angular.js`):

```
Error: $injector:nomod
Module Unavailable
Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

The first error is really painful to solve. The second one is much more easier.

Happy coding!

Comment: How to solve the first one? I am not getting any error when use the unminified version.

Comment: Well, I used to check dependencies of `eduApp` one by one. And I used to search in git log to see (to narrow down) what might have caused the problem. It was tedious process for me though. However, the behavior of your app may suggests that there is a problem in the minification itself - I would check that first.

Answer (score 23):

[Minified AngularJS gives me unreadable errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110120/minified-angularjs-gives-me-unreadable-errors#comment31760167_21110120)

> ... Use the unminified version in development to make it easier to debug.

Comment: I am using the unminified version

Comment: Using the unminified version is the answer

Answer (score 12):

I found the following approach to be somewhat helpful.  Use local `angular.js` file so you can modify it:

1. Open your `angular.js` file
2. Go to lines with the following code:

   ```
   message = message + '\nhttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/' +
     (module ? module + '/' : '') + code;
   ```
3. After these two lines add:

   ```
   console.log(message);
   ```

Taken from here: http://www.chrisgmyr.com/2014/08/debugging-uncaught-error-injectormodulerr-in-angularjs/

Comment: so simple yet so effective. they should have an angular.debug.js with this built in...