# angular js syntax errors

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am enough familiar with Javascript as I use it in ajax for PHP but new to AngularJS.

During my first angularJs assignment from "tutorialspoint" I got following error in console:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=mainApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.14%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DmainApp%0AM%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A417%0AOd%2F%3C%2F%3C%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A412%0Aa%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A53%0AOd%2F%3C%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A1%0Ag%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A46%0As%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A300%0Ag%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A34%3A399%0Aab%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A135%0Atc%2Fd%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381%0Atc%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A179%0AJd%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A1%0A%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A249%3A428%0Aa%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A163%3A399%0Alf%2Fc%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%3A384%0A

Which is not readable at all.

I tried `try{} catch(){}` but, didn't work.

I couldn't use `alert()` as angularJS doesn't execute in line.

So I checked line by line and I found out that I had written:

```
var firstApp = angular.module("mainAp", []);
```

where I had misspelled `data-ng-app` which should have been `mainApp`.
But I couldn't have figured it out if there was 300 lines of code.
so, I wanted to know if there is any simple way to show error very specifically like in php.

Comment: Looks like `$http` is not injected. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

> "[...] which is not readable at all."

You are using the minified angular.min.js version of Angular. That is a good thing for production (as the file is really smaller), but you can use angular.js during development if you want more readable errors.

---

To illustrate, this is what you get with the minified version:

> Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error Failed to instantiate module
>   mainApp due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=e...)
>       at Error (native)
>       at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:6:416
>       at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:38:184
>       at m (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:7:322)
>       at h (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:37:275)
>       at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:37:444
>       at m (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:7:322)
>       at h (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:37:275)
>       ...

And with the unminified version:

> Error: `$injector:nomod`
>   Module Unavailable
>   Module `'ui.bootstrap'` is not
>   available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
>   If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as
>   the second argument.

<sub>[Examples source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247444/how-to-debug-angular-injectormodulerr-errors)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for answer..But i still think debugging javascript code is tough