# Issue w/firebase.js and Angular UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angular-ui-router, angularfire

I'm integrating firebase with AngularJS, and I'm having some trouble using the result of a firebase snapshot in a promise.

Below is the code in one of my states in ui-router:

```
                resolve: {
                    opinionConfig: function($stateParams, $location, $q, ConstantsService) {
                        var result = $q.defer();
                        var processResponse = function(value) {
                            value.opinion = $stateParams.opinion;
                            result.resolve(value);
                        };

                        var rootRef = new Firebase(ConstantsService.FIREBASE_URL + 'configs/' + $stateParams.opinion);

                        rootRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.val() === null) {
                                $location.path('/');
                                // console.log("configs doesn't exist.");
                                result.reject("configs doesn't exist");
                            } else {
                                // console.log("configs does exist: " + snapshot.val());
                                processResponse(angular.copy(snapshot.val()));
                            }
                        });

                        return result.promise;
                    }
                }
```

and I'm getting this error in firefox's developer tools.

[image]

and this is what I get in Chrome's developer tools.

[image]

It seems like the two errors are different, and I couldn't find an official un-minified version of firebase.js, so I wasn't sure where exactly this is being thrown.

Thanks,

Luke

Answer (score 1):

You are using min version of js *(the error says `angular.min`...)*

and then this

```
opinionConfig: function($stateParams, $location, $q, ConstantsService) {
```

is converted into this

```
opinionConfig: function(c, x, g, r) { // an example showing minification
```

so what we have to do is:

```
opinionConfig: 
['$stateParams', '$location', '$q', 'ConstantsService',
function($stateParams, $location, $q, ConstantsService) {
```

maybe check also this [Minified AngularJS gives me unreadable errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110120/)

Comment: I'm getting the same error even after escaping the injections.

Comment: Then you have to search for more declarations like this... That is my 99,9% suspected...

Comment: If I just return a normal object without changing the signature.  There's no error.  I suspect it might be the promise issue.  I also uploaded the error i see in Chrome.

Comment: Gb really could come from minified version of the firebase, but the issue I see, is that the Gb is not found on the null... so it would be on our (not firebase) side... could you create a plunker?

Comment: Okay.  Let me create one.

Comment: It doesn't even crash consistently